# Change comparator of treemap during runtime

Tags: java, comparator, treemap

I see that the only way to set a comparator is via the TreeMap constructor.  For instance:

```
 TreeMap myMap = new TreeMap(myComparator);
```

However, I would like to decide what type of comparator to use during runtime.  I could create multiple TreeMaps or a new instance of one, but I find that it leaves a bigger memory footprint.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there a design flaw on my end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you defer the creation of the `TreeMap` until you know which `Comparator` will be appropriate. If this is not possible (e.g. because you need to initialize other objects with a reference to the `TreeMap`), consider hiding the `TreeMap` behind a method or class that will lazily initialize it, or using the Factory pattern.

If this is also impossible, initialize the `TreeMap` with your own `Comparator` implementation, and make the decision there (`compareTo()` won't be invoked until you start adding items to the `TreeMap`). If you go this route, you must take great care to *not change the comparator behavior after you've started adding items to the tree!*

As for *why* `TreeMap` (or most other collections that take a `Comparator`) won't allow you to change the `Comparator`, see @Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer.

Comment: Or, create a new TreeMap with the changed Comparator, and putAll from the existing one.

Comment: @user949300: That would work too, but it could become messy if the `TreeMap` is referenced from many places (which will all need to be updated).

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap does not allow to change Comparator because the internal tree structure depends on the Comparator and changing it would make the internal tree invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
class MyCompartor<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    Comparator<T> changeableComparator;
    public void setComparator(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.changeableComparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return changeableComparator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

But this would be crazy. You can not and must not change the `TreeMap`'s `Comparator` during runtime. The tree will not reorganize itself according to the new `Comparator`.

Instead, create a new `TreeMap` for each new `Comparator` (that is if you can't initialize the map when the comparison type is known as others have suggested).

Alternatively, subclass TreeMap and add a reorganize method with the above changeable `Comparator`, but really this is pretty much the same (performance wise) as creating a new `TreeMap`. The only thing you'r eliminating is the memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your Comparators in a way like this:

```
//first impl
final Comparator<String> first = new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }
};

//second impl
final Comparator<String> second = new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }
};

Comparator<String> inst=first;

//Treemap initialization
TreeMap<String, String> t = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        //call of the impl
        return inst.compare(o1, o2);
    }
});


.....
//switch during runtime
inst = second;

....
```